# How to update insert JSON property in an array of object with T-SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I am trying to find an effective way to insert a property into an existing json array with out having to do it by index. For example say we had:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'
  {
    "objs":[
       {"id":1},
       {"id":2}
     ]
  }
'
```

How do I add a property to each object in the array? What I would like to do is something like this:

```
JSON_MODIFY(@json,'$.objs[].parent_id',1);
```

But this does not work because I did not provide an array index. I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I could not find one in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2017+, you may use `JSON_MODIFY()` with an expression as path, as is explained in the documentation:

> In SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and in Azure SQL Database, you can provide a
>   variable as the value of path.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'{
   "objs":[
      {
         "id":1
      },
      {
         "id":2
      }
   ]
}';
```

Statement:

```
SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, CONCAT('$.objs[', [key], '].parent_id'), 1)
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.objs')
```

Result:

```
{
   "objs":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "parent_id":1
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "parent_id":1
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for Thanks!

Comment: Link to `JSON_MODIFY()` in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use `OPENJSON` and `FOR JSON` to shred and combine the JSON:

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @json = N'{
  "objs": [{
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 2
  }]
}';

SELECT id, 1 AS parent_id
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.objs')
WITH (
    id INT '$.id'
)
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('objs')
```

Result:

```js
{
  "objs": [{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": 1
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1
  }]
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was bout to try. I was just hoping for a better way. Thanks!

Comment: `JSON_MODIFY` wont help since it modifies one property at a time. This solution should be OK unless you don't know the name of keys in child object in advance.